# Show/Hide Featured Image or replace it with custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I want in the place of the featured image of a post -depending on the subject of the post-, to show shortcodes (example shortcode to put on custom field:[ngg_images gallery_ids="1" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_slideshow"]), emebed tweets (example link to put on custom field: https://twitter.com/nikestore/status/471416532317532160). emebed instagram photos (example link to put on custom field: http://instagram.com/p/oJjacIgUXk/) or anything else.

I want two different codes that will do the things below:

1. If I have only put something on the specific custom field, it would show only that and not the featured image or else if I haven’t added anything there then it will show the featured image.
2. If there is anything on that specific custom field, then it won’t show the featured image, if there isn’t anything on that field then it would show the featured image.

I made this [code](http://pastebin.com/thQkStqQ)  but it showed me the featured image and what I added on the custom field.

Then I tried what it was saying on that [reply](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103529/12508) which isn't what I want but it works only with the shortcodes and with some conflicts. It doesn't support tweets, nor instagram photos or anything else. Which is the right way to make it work?

Comment: What is $short variable?

Comment: the name of custom field

Comment: I think the $short variable is undefined then (if you don't define it anywhere) so the if condition is always false. And you output do_shortcode out of if statement always. Below is correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
$myfield = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short', true);

if ($myfield) {
  echo do_shortcode($myfield);
} else {
  the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Comment: and if i want to add a div class (<div class="featuredimage"></div>) on fled and on thumbnail?

Comment: Add `<div class="featuredimage"><?php` before my code, and `?></div>` after it.

Comment: I have updated my question, check it out.